# Error Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException'

Tags: php, joomla

In my error log I founds thousands of this:

Joomla Version 3.3.6

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message
>   'Duplicate entry 'http://www.dualda.de/index.php?option=999999.9'
>   /**/uNiOn/**/aLl' for key 'idx_link_old' SQL=INSERT INTO
>   `ade39_redirect_links`, referer: http://www.dualda.de/

Any idea?

Comment: Your query to insert into ade39_redirect_links keeps trying to insert a value for a unique key that has already been inserted. You need to look at the query and either ensure the key is unique before doing the query or change the unique key.

Comment: This question is about Joomla specific implementation details, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)